# How to do Exclusion Queries in OrientDB

Tags: graph, subquery, orientdb

I'm wondering if it's possible to use a sub-selection as an exclusion query in orient db (v2.0). Or if it's necessary to export separate queries and process in Java/PHP/etc.

For instance, say we have the following graph for Hogwarts.

Vertices
People, Houses, Classes

Edges
is_at (subclasses is_student, is_faculty), was_at (alumni), is_taking, is_teaching, belongs_to

How would we find all the alumni who aren't also faculty? Is it possible to do so as a single query or using LET somehow?

How would we find all the faculty who are teaching a course on, say, time travel, that have no students who belong to the house gryffindor?

Thanks,
Lindsay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .size() operator should work: http://orientdb.com/docs/2.0/orientdb.wiki/SQL-Methods.html#size

```
select from People where out('is_faculty').size() = 0
```

Use out('...') or in('...') based on your graph.

> How would we find all the faculty you are teaching a course on, say, time travel, that have no students who belong to the house gryffindor?

I don't have much information on your graph and classes, but that could be something like:

```
select from Classes where ClassName='time travel' and in('is_teaching')[Id=yourId] and in('is_taking').out('belongs_to')[Name='gryffindor'].size() = 0
```

Again, use in() or out() accordingly to your graph.